# Docker unable to mount nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-toolbox

I'm having issues setting up Docker for the first time on a Windows using the Docker Toolbox. Everything works except nginx at the moment.

Error message:

```
ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/c/wamp64/www/cathaypacific_career/ops/nginx/default.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/ff9b27a89b26b0e9091264d04d3a475f18469db3cf3be473c005e2d4c7d4b5ef\\\" at \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/ff9b27a89b26b0e9091264d04d3a475f18469db3cf3be473c005e2d4c7d4b5ef/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Docker-compose config:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    image: nginx:1.13.3-alpine
    networks:
      - web_tier
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ../:/code
      - /code/ops/
    depends_on:
      - app
  app:
    container_name: app
    build: ./php/
    networks:
      - web_tier
      - app_tier
    expose:
      - '9000'
    volumes:
      - ./php/settings.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/settings.conf
      - ../:/code
      - /code/ops/
    working_dir: /code
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c"
    command:
      - "php-fpm"
    env_file: ../.env
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:5.6.39
    networks:
      - app_tier
      - db_tier
    expose:
      - '3306'
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
       - ./db:/etc/mysql/conf.d
    restart: always
    env_file: ../.env
networks:
  web_tier:
    driver: bridge
  app_tier:
    driver: bridge
  db_tier:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db_data:
```

The issue seems to be related to Nginx with the default.conf not being accessible or the app thinkgs it's a folder and not a file. 
I checked the issue online and people suggests to mount the C: folder so I tried to mount it on Oracle VirtualBox and re-run the `docker-compose up` command but it didn't solve the issue.

Any idea?

Comment: can you provide defalut.conf

Comment: that's too long - but basically just a nginx config (listen port 80, root of the code...) 

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /code/public;

Comment: I'm having the same issue with `nginx:alpine` on WIndows. The odd part is that it worked fine yesterday evening and when I tried to start it back up this morning that error started appearing.

Answer (score 1):

I solved same problem with sharing folder with `Oracle VirtualBox VM default`

[image]

Share your project folder and restart your vm.

You can do even with command like
 `docker-machine stop default` & `docker-machine stop default`

Now, you need to use shared name (project) instead of `.` in your compose file (`docker-compose.yml`)

For your case,

`- ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

should changed to

`- /sharename/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

Now try with `docker-compose up`.

It worked for me.