# How to mount a directory in windows on a container with Kubernetes on Docker for Windows?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, docker-for-windows

I am using Docker for Windows 2.3.0.4 (stable) backed by WSL2 on Windows 10 version 2004 and with Kubernetes support enabled.

I am trying to create the following pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: api0
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: "mongo-data"
      hostPath:
        path: "/c/wr/volumes/mongo/data"
  containers:
  - name: db
    image: mongo:3.6.19-xenial
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/data/db"
        name: "mongo-data"
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "512Mi"
        cpu: "1"
    ports:
      - containerPort: 27017
```

I have an issue with the `mongo-data` volume; when the pod is created via `kubectl apply -f api0.yml` the pod runs properly and the MongoDB collections are persisted after deleting and re-applying the pod.

But the `C:\wr\volumes\mongo\data` path that is mounted to the mongo db container does not contain the data files and **is always empty**

As I mentioned before, the state is persisted somewhere but not in the specified path.

**What am I missing?**

I tried specifying the path with the following formats:

- /c/wr/volumes/mongo/data
- //c/wr/volumes/mongo/data
- //////c/wr/volumes/mongo/data
- /mnt/c/wr/volumes/mongo/data

And I even tried referencing the `/opt/data` path in the wsl filesystem but the data files are never there.

Comment: Have you followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018812/docker-for-windows-volumes-are-empty to make sure the drive is shared?

Comment: Yes, the C Drive is shared and I am able to mount directories under C: to docker containers with the docker cli

Comment: how  exactly you are checking if the `C:\wr\volumes\mongo\data` is empty?  Have you been trying stop the pod, move that folder somewhere else and then create folder from scratch,  start the pod and check if all the collections persist?

Comment: I check the content of the folder in the windows file explorer. Hidden Files @Nick ?

Comment: please add your PV and PVC configuration files .

Comment: `kubectl get pods api0  -o wide` shall give you the node the container is running on. Do you have only one Windows node or multiple ones? Are you checking on the correct node? what does `kubectl describe pod api0` say ?  Do you see the correct volume mounts there?  Are you able  you login to the pod and check if the `/data/db` is not empty?

Comment: @Chedy2149 I am facing the same issue, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @coderji unfortunately no